# Can't use React within html

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to use React directly in html without setting up a react environment. I can only see the test suite in the browser but my react app is not loading.

this is my script.js file:

I commented out the imports because I don't need them if I have script tags in my html file.

````
// import * as React from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/react@17.0.1";
// import * as ReactDOM from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/react-dom@17.0.1";
// import { marked } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/marked@4.0.18";

const useState = React.useState;

marked.setOptions({
  breaks: true,
  highlight: function (code) {
    return;
    Prism.highlight(code, Prism.languages.javascript, "javascript");
  }
});

const renderer = new marked.Renderer();

const firstInput =
  "# H1\n" +
  "## H2\n" +
  "### H3\n" +
  "Here's a [link](https://www.freecodecamp.org)\n\n" +
  "Heres some code, `<div></div>`, between 2 backticks.\n" +
  "```\n" +
  "// this is multi-line code:\n" +
  "function anotherExample(firstLine, lastLine) {\n" +
  "if (firstLine == '```' && lastLine == '```') {\n" +
  "  return multiLineCode;\n" +
  " }\n" +
  "}\n" +
  "```\n" +
  "> Block Quotes!\n" +
  "- And of course there are lists.\n" +
  " - Some are bulleted.\n" +
  "   - With different indentation levels.\n" +
  "     - That look like this.\n" +
  "1. And there are numbered lists too.\n" +
  "1. Use just 1s if you want!\n" +
  "1. And last but not least, let's not forget embedded images:\n\n" +
  "**Here's a bold text** \n" +
  "![React Logo](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/main/src/icons/logo.svg)  \n";

const App = () => {
  const [markdown, setMarkdown] = useState(firstInput);

  const handleOnChange = (event) => {
    setMarkdown(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div id="text-center">
      <h1 id="header">Markdown Previewer</h1>
      <div id="wrapper">
        <div className="editor-wrap">
          <div className="toolbar"> Editor</div>
          <textarea
            cols="50"
            rows="50"
            id="editor"
            value={markdown}
            onChange={handleOnChange}
            placeholder=""
          >
            {markdown}
          </textarea>
        </div>
        <div className="preview-wrap">
          <div className="toolbar"> Preview</div>
          <div
            id="preview"
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: marked(markdown, { renderer: renderer })
            }}
          ></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
````

this is my index.html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Markdown Previewer</title>
</head>

<body>
 <script src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/v1/bundle.js"></script>

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/4.0.18/marked.min.js"></script>

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>

 <script src="script.js"></script>

 <div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Place your script tag after `root`

Comment: It did but it's still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should visit http://localhost/... to run it,you need a server or visual code

Comment: I want to use in directly in the html without localhost.